# Debug buttons are missing

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

My debug buttons(like breakepoint button(F5),go to next line(F8),step into(F7) etc.)were suddenly disappeared.How to bring them back without restoring all settings to default?

[image: no buttons]

Comment: Btw can anyone explain why I get -1?I havent found any duplicate questions and I dont think this question too dumb.

Comment: @AbAppletic Im 100 percent sure I done something wrong.If I were remmembered that I done, I would just reversed my actions.But in this case I would not ask a question in a first place.

Comment: You should still include your Android Studio version, your OS, etc. Edit your post with this information and I'll replace my downvote with an upvote

Comment: @AliBdeir this is still happening in 2021 with AS 4.2

Answer (score 33):

[image]

Faced the same issue. Should just select the option "Show toolbar" in the debugger "gear" icon menu. Android studio 4.0.

UPD: for the last AS it is not "gear" icon, but 3 vertical dots. But menu is similar.

Answer (score 3):

Ok i found this little button in the right corner.Just press it and your buttons will be restored.

[image]